# Mongoose find documents from two collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Is it possible to find documents from separete collections in one query and sort them?

For example when you searching on youtube there may be mixed results of authors and videos.

Comment: Lookup to [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to query 2 collections together. You can perform the 2 queries in 'parallel' (using [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel), [es6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), or many others techniques) and then sort the results.